# mudar a cor da letra dentro da tag pre

Tags: html, html5

Tenho a seguinte tag pre simulando código js

```
<pre class="text" id="text-two" style="margin-left: -29% !important;margin-top: -8.5%;">
                                    <h1> Deshboard codando mais um bot pra você!!</h1> 
                                function newBot(name, ID, Object){
                            this.name = name;
                        this.id = ID;
                                this.object = Object;
                                                return new Bot(this.name, this.id, this.object)
}</pre>
```

colocando esse tanto de espaço no site ele fica certinho porem queria colocar uma cor diferente na tag h1 e na função como eu posso alterar a cor da letra em um lugar especifico dentro do pre??

Comment: Você quer colorir, simulando o highlight a linguagem?

Comment: simm, simulando um editor sabe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criar um *highlight de sintaxe* não é tão simples, se você deseja apenas focar na parte de colorir a sintaxe do seu código e não de como fazer isso, você pode optar por utilizar uma lib pronta para essa tarefa.

---

Um exemplo de lib para criar o *highlight da sintaxe* é a
[highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/), abaixo um exemplo de sua utilização:

```html
<pre class="text" id="text-two">
 <h1> Deshboard codando mais um bot pra você!!</h1> 
  <code class="javascript">
 function newBot(name, ID, Object){
  this.name = name;
  this.id = ID;
  this.object = Object;
  return new Bot(this.name, this.id, this.object)
 }
  </code>
</pre>

<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Um outra lib é a [prettify](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify), mas é válido citar que ela não recebe mais manutenções, veja um exemplo utilizando ela:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>

<h1> Deshboard codando mais um bot pra você!!</h1> 

<pre class="text prettyprint" id="text-two">
function newBot(name, ID, Object){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = ID;
    this.object = Object;
    return new Bot(this.name, this.id, this.object)
}
</pre>
```

Existe muitas outras libs com essa mesma finalidade, tais como [microlight](https://asvd.github.io/microlight/), [rainbow](https://craig.is/making/rainbows), [prismjs](https://prismjs.com/)... Nessa [pergunta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160694/syntax-highlighting-code-with-javascript) em inglês eles citam algumas outras, vale a pena dar uma lida.

---

Por fim, para colorir um `h1`, não há segredo, você pode optar por utilizar um `Inline CSS`:

```html
<h1 style="color: blue;"> Deshboard codando mais um bot pra você!!</h1>
```

Um `External CSS`:

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1> Deshboard codando mais um bot pra você!!</h1>
```

Ou um `Internal CSS`:

```html
<style>
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<h1> Deshboard codando mais um bot pra você!!</h1>
```

> Documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_syntax_highlight.asp